# How to setup a nx workspace for plain javascript (Cannot find module 'typescript')?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, npm, nrwl-nx, nx-devkit

I want to create a nx workspace for plain react apps.

Create Workspace

```
npx create-nx-workspace@latest # installs 15.2.1
# style: package-based
# distributed caching: NO
```

Install react-package

```
npm install -D @nrwl/react
```

Create js react app

```
npx nx g @nrwl/react:app my-new-app --js
```

But if I try to start the app

```
npx nx serve my-new-app
```

I get following error:

[image]

Why is the module `typescript` needed in a plain js app? Or why is it not installed when it is needed?

Thanks

Comment: can you include how you've set up via `npx create-nx-workspace@latest`? And for posthumous reasons I assume version is 15.2.0

Comment: Unable to reproduce error.  Used integrated, react default app, css, yes to distributed caching

Comment: @AndrewAllen Thanks for your response. I updated my question with the options. I just tested it with 15.2.1. But I want to build a package-based monorepo with multiple react-apps and libs.

Comment: Do I need `create-react-app` with `craco` if I want to use a package-based approach?

Answer (score 1):

I've had this as well with `@nrwl/js` in a package based monorepo setup using `create-nx-workspace`, where I tried to run `@nrwl/js:init` but it seems to do nothing, and then `@nrwl/js:lib` gives me the error `Cannot find tsconfig.base.json`.

If I instead use `create-nx-workspace` to choose an integrated monorepo setup, and choose to use the `ts` option for an empty monorepo with the JS/TS plugin preinstalled, then it is setup correctly.

Perhaps generating the repo with the integrated react setup can help you pin down what's missing for your package based setup.

Apart from that, perhaps you could check the Nx Github to see if there's any issue relevant, e.g. the one below:

- https://github.com/nrwl/nx/issues/1682

To me it seems like a bug, or at least, if its not being used in the intended way, its a user experience issue that may they need to improve - perhaps its documented on the website, but for beginners, just using `create-nx-workspace` should be the easiest way to get started.

**Update:** I see that the [Package-Based Repo Tutorial](https://nx.dev/getting-started/package-based-repo-tutorial) actually does mention to install TypeScript manually, but my point above still remains - `create-nx-workspace` should do the work I need to create a workspace, TypeScript seems required for most if not all workspaces, so having it as a manual step seems to defeat the point.